# Not able to update new content in webview in fragment in android

Tags: android

I have added two fragment in layout. One fragment is list view and one fragment is webview. In webview first showing default data. If the user clicks on list view data, I am not able to update new content in webview in fragment in android. Can anybody tell me what the problem is? How do I do this? See below my code. It's working in the emulator but not on the device.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posistion, 
            long id) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                checkTablet=isTablet();
                if(checkTablet)
                {

                    webFragment=(WebViewFragment1)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.webFrag);
                    //webView=(WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadWeb);
                //WebViewFragment1 webViewFragment=(WebViewFragment1).findViewById(R.id.loadWeb);
                    //webFragment=(WebViewFragment1)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.webFrag);
                    DataGenerator dataGenerator=new DataGenerator();
                    String data=dataGenerator.getData(posistion);
                    System.out.println("data is"+data);
                    //webView.loadData(data, "html/data", "utf-8");
                    webFragment.loadWeb.loadData(data, "html/data", "utf-8");

                }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to add a **fragmentTransaction**, just like this:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

ft.replace(R.id.webFrag, your fragment);
ft.setTransition(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
ft.commit();
```